# Cant get my queries to show when calling them

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am trying to get the items to show that Im adding to my data base. The problem is I think i have the right code to show but I cant tell if its adding to the database for me to check. Need someone to look at code in question tell me how to fix so i can show stuff or if mabye create function is broke. if I take out the forloop in the index it will show the other html but when forloop is up it doesnt.

now added user = Myblackbelt.objects.add_product(request.POST) to send info to post and it give new error

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\upload\blackbelttest\apps\blackbeltapp\views.py" in create
  43.   user = Myblackbelt.objects.add_product(request.POST)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\upload\blackbelttest\apps\blackbeltapp\models.py" in add_product
  7.        Myblackbelt = self.create(product = postData['product'] )

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  399.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  796.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  824.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  908.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  947.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1045.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1054.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in **exit**
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  337.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /blackbelt/create
Exception Value: blackbeltapp_myblackbelt.creator_id may not be NULL

```
 new.html  part that is submitting

     <form class="" action="{% url 'blackbelt:create' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <p>Product: <input type="text" name="product" value=""></p>
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Create">
            </form>

    index.html   part that is showing

            <h2>Your Wish List</h2>
                     <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Added By</th>
                        <th>Date Added</th>
                        <th>Remove From Wish List</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>

                    </tr>
                    {% for dog in wishlist%}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{dog.item}}</td>
                        <td>{{dog.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{dog.created_at}}</td>
                        <td><a href="">Show</a></td>
                        <td><a href="">Edit</td>
                        <td><form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Remove"></form></td>
                      {% endfor%}
                    </tr>

                </table>


    views.py
def index(request):
    context = {

    'wishlist':Myblackbelt.objects.all()

    }
    return render(request, 'blackbeltapp/index.html', context)

    def create(request):


        return redirect ('blackbelt:index')

    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.db import models
    from ..logReg.models import User

    class ProductManager(models.Manager):
        def add_product(self, postData):
            user = self.create(item = postData['product'] )
            print 'dog here'


    models.py

    class Myblackbelt(models.Model):
        item = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
        dateadded=models.CharField(max_length = 10)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
        loguser = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='loguser')
        creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator')


        objects = ProductManager()
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly is your problem? Also please make sure that your code is indented correctly.

Comment: I need my index to show the items in the data base. But I cant see if stuff im adding is going in the database

Comment: Well your create function does not appear to have any code to create anything.

Comment: the create function is just there to pull the postData the create function is in the model

Comment: Yes, but you haven't written anything to actually get that post data or pass it to the model create method.

Comment: i havent had to before the whats it post the model nomrally grabs it what am i missing?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Of course you need to write code to do things. How would your addProduct method be called otherwise?

Comment: def add_product(self, postData):
  user = self.create(item = postData['product'] )  are you saing my def is not pulling my post?

Comment: Yes I saw that code but *how are you expecting it to be called*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138974/discussion-between-david-hollenbeck-and-daniel-roseman).

Answer (score -1):

Finally found the answer. I had a corrupt database. After I deleted it and rebuilt it worked.